# Riak and index - how to check the index a particular bucket has?

Tags: riak

I am very much new to riak and I am currently using it with an API. So, let me explain my scenario.

There is an account - say example@riaktest.com created under accounts bucket.
So, on doing

`localhost:8098/buckets/accounts/keys?keys=true` it returns `{{"keys":["example@riaktest.com"]}}`

So, i basically have one 'key' with other data fields inside.

Now, I have a functionality that a user can join a particular group. Lets say, 'group1'. 
He logs in, joins group1. I give the snowflake generated ID of the account as the index.

Question is:

How do I see a particular key's list of index?

`localhost:8098/riak/group/group1` will give me the values and the main account it is tied to.

Comment: My question here in short is, `http://localhost:8098/buckets/group/index/??_bin/ACT1136313732239065088` where the ACT11...088 is the account id that is used as index and stored in the group1. How do i determine the _bin files? And also how will I know whether that particular key-value has got many indeces .Please give me insights. Thank you

Comment: why not store groups in account? /account/<key> => { ..., groups: [] }